# Hiding the PyQt statusBar message with permanent widgets

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I want to have permanent `statusBar`() since I have multiple permanent widgets in it but I want to hide the status messages. The `clearMessage`() function does not seem to work in this case. Is there any solutions for this?

Example:

```
self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(x)
self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(y)
self.statusBar().clearMessage()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "status messages", and what is producing them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.